# Javascript reference error - can't find a function inside object

Tags: javascript

```
var model = {

   test:function(){console.log("hello")},

   show: test() //ReferenceError: test is not defined
}
```

I want to have a key inside model object to hold a function. Not sure why it gets undefined error.

Comment: You can't reference the contents of an object literal from inside while it's "under construction". You have to use a separate statement.

Comment: You mean I can only call this function outside of object?

Comment: Yes. There's just no way to do it in JavaScript all inside a single object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a duplicate but I can't find a good one. You have to do something like this:

```
var model = {

   test:function(){console.log("hello")},

};
model.show = model.test();
```

If you want to make it less ... primitive, I guess, you can write a constructor function to encapsulate that stuff, or perhaps a "factory"-like function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps .

```js
var model = {

  test: function() {
    alert("hello")
  },
  show: function() {
    return this.test();
  }
}

model.test();
model.show();
```

use key show as a function, return test from it.